# EMGU CV, Visual Basic CameraCalibration.CalibrateCamera resulting in very high error

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, emgucv, camera-calibration

I have been going over many different resources trying to find a information on camera calibration for VB.

My best luck so far has been reading the example on the site for C#
[shown in this link with pictures and source files.](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Calibration)

I have converted as much of the code as I could from C# to VB, and tried to find as much working code for everything else. So far my MainWindow.vb code is:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Threading

Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure



Class MainWindow
'Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
'       Handles Me.Loaded
'    Dim capturez As Capture = New Capture

'End Sub
#Region "Class Variables"
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByRef Milliseconds As Integer)
Dim capturez As Capture = New Capture
Dim Start_Flag As Boolean = False

Dim BoxUnitHeight As Integer = 9 'EDIT THESE VALUES BASED ON THE BOARD PATTERN
Dim BoxUnitWidth As Integer = 6

Dim Frame_array_buffer As Image(Of Gray, [Byte])() = New Image(Of Gray, Byte)(99) {}
Dim BufferSavePoint As Integer = 0
Dim Corner_Object_List As MCvPoint3D32f()() = New     MCvPoint3D32f(Frame_array_buffer.Length - 1)() {}
Dim Corner_Points_List As PointF()() = New PointF(Frame_array_buffer.Length - 1)() {}
Dim IC As New IntrinsicCameraParameters()
Dim EX_Param As ExtrinsicCameraParameters() = New ExtrinsicCameraParameters() {}

Dim patternSize As Size = New Size(BoxUnitHeight, BoxUnitWidth)

Dim Gray_Frame As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = capturez.QueryGrayFrame
Dim BGR_Frame As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.RetrieveBgrFrame
Dim calImage As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = New Image(Of Gray, Byte)    ("C:\Users\\\\\\Image_Correction_Test_V2\OpenCV_Chessboard.png")

Dim corners As PointF() = New PointF() {}
Dim newCornerz As PointF() = New PointF() {}

Dim difError As Double
Dim termCriteria As New MCvTermCriteria


Public Enum Mode
    SavingFrames
    Caluculating_Intrinsics
    Calibrated
End Enum
#End Region
Private currentMode As Mode = Mode.SavingFrames

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Loaded
    termCriteria.max_iter = 1
    termCriteria.epsilon = 0.0
    termCriteria.type = CvEnum.TERMCRIT.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER

End Sub
' Sink the "Exit MenuItem" click event
Private Sub mnuExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) _
        Handles mnuExit.Click
    Application.Current.Shutdown()
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) _
    Handles Button.Click
    Start_Flag = True
End Sub

' Sink the "Exit MenuItem" click event
Private Sub mnuFix_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) _
        Handles mnuFix.Click
    Gray_Frame = capturez.RetrieveGrayFrame
    newCornerz = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(calImage, patternSize,      Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH Or Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.FILTER_QUADS)

    corners = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(Gray_Frame, patternSize,     Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH Or Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.FILTER_QUADS)

    If corners IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim perM As HomographyMatrix
        perM = CameraCalibration.FindHomography(corners, newCornerz,     CvEnum.HOMOGRAPHY_METHOD.DEFAULT, 1)
        Dim Test As Image(Of Gray, Byte) = Gray_Frame.WarpPerspective(perM,     CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_NN, CvEnum.WARP.CV_WARP_DEFAULT, New Gray)
        Cal1.Source = ToBitmapSource(Test)
    End If

End Sub


Public Sub StartTimer(ByVal o As Object, ByVal sender As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim myDispatcherTimer As System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer = New     System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
    myDispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 30)
    ' 100 Milliseconds 
    AddHandler myDispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf Me.Each_Tick
    myDispatcherTimer.Start()
End Sub

' Raised every 100 miliseconds while the DispatcherTimer is active.
Public Sub Each_Tick(ByVal o As Object, ByVal sender As EventArgs)

    Dim imagez As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame() 'Instead of QueryFrame, you may need to do RetrieveBgrFrame depending on the version of EmguCV you download.
    Stream.Source = ToBitmapSource(imagez)

    BGR_Frame = capturez.RetrieveBgrFrame
    Gray_Frame = BGR_Frame.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()

    If currentMode = Mode.SavingFrames Then

        corners = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(Gray_Frame, patternSize, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH Or Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.FILTER_QUADS)

        If corners IsNot Nothing Then
            'Debug.Print("Filling Array Buffer")

            'The Find chessboardCorners will try to find them, but if it doesn't it still runs. If it fails DrawChessboard will fail and crash the program.

            If Start_Flag Then
                Gray_Frame.FindCornerSubPix(New PointF(0)() {corners}, New Size(11, 11), New Size(-1, -1), New MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1))
                Frame_array_buffer(BufferSavePoint) = Gray_Frame.Copy
                BufferSavePoint = BufferSavePoint + 1
                If BufferSavePoint = Frame_array_buffer.Length Then currentMode = Mode.Caluculating_Intrinsics 'Buffer has been filled
            End If


            'Draw the reults

            CameraCalibration.DrawChessboardCorners(Gray_Frame, patternSize, corners)
            Cal2.Source = ToBitmapSource(Gray_Frame)
            Thread.Sleep(100)

        End If
        corners = Nothing
    End If

    If currentMode = Mode.Caluculating_Intrinsics Then
        'Debug.Print("Filling Object and Point Arrays")
        For k As Integer = 0 To Frame_array_buffer.Length - 1

            Corner_Points_List(k) = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(Frame_array_buffer(k), patternSize, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH)
            'for accuracy
            Gray_Frame.FindCornerSubPix(Corner_Points_List, New Size(11, 11), New Size(-1, -1), New MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1))

            'Fill our objects list with the real world mesurments for the intrinsic calculations
            Dim object_list As New List(Of MCvPoint3D32f)()
            For i As Integer = 0 To BoxUnitHeight - 1
                For j As Integer = 0 To BoxUnitWidth - 1
                    object_list.Add(New MCvPoint3D32f(j * 20.0F, i * 20.0F, 0.0F))
                Next
            Next
            Corner_Object_List(k) = object_list.ToArray()
        Next
        Debug.Print("Reached Calibration")

        'our error should be as close to 0 as possible

        difError = CameraCalibration.CalibrateCamera(Corner_Object_List, Corner_Points_List, Gray_Frame.Size, IC, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_TYPE.CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL, termCriteria, EX_Param)
        'If Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_TYPE == CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS and/or CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO are specified, some or all of fx, fy, cx, cy must be initialized before calling the function
        'if you use FIX_ASPECT_RATIO and FIX_FOCAL_LEGNTH options, these values needs to be set in the intrinsic parameters before the CalibrateCamera function is called. Otherwise 0 values are used as default.
        'display the results to the user
        MsgBox("Your calibration error is:" & difError)
        currentMode = Mode.Calibrated
    End If

    If currentMode = Mode.Calibrated Then
        'Debug.Print("Attempting Picture fix")


        'calculate the camera intrinsics
        Dim Map1 As Matrix(Of Single), Map2 As Matrix(Of Single)
        IC.InitUndistortMap(BGR_Frame.Width, BGR_Frame.Height, Map1, Map2)

        'remap the image to the particular intrinsics
        'In the current version of EMGU any pixel that is not corrected is set to transparent allowing the original image to be displayed if the same
        'image is mapped backed, in the future this should be controllable through the flag '0'
        Dim temp As Image(Of Bgr, [Byte]) = BGR_Frame.CopyBlank()
        CvInvoke.cvRemap(BGR_Frame, temp, Map1, Map2, 0, New MCvScalar(0))
        BGR_Frame = temp.Copy


        Imgz.Source = ToBitmapSource(BGR_Frame)
        Start_Flag = False
    End If

    Debug.Print(currentMode)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Delete a GDI object
''' </summary>
''' <param name="o">The poniter to the GDI object to be deleted</param>
''' <returns></returns>
<DllImport("gdi32")> _
Private Shared Function DeleteObject(o As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Convert an IImage to a WPF BitmapSource. The result can be used in the Set Property of Image.Source
''' </summary>
''' <param name="image">The Emgu CV Image</param>
''' <returns>The equivalent BitmapSource</returns>
Public Shared Function ToBitmapSource(image As IImage) As BitmapSource
    Using source As System.Drawing.Bitmap = image.Bitmap
        Dim ptr As IntPtr = source.GetHbitmap()
        'obtain the Hbitmap
        Dim bs As BitmapSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ptr, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())

        DeleteObject(ptr)
        'release the HBitmap
        Return bs
    End Using
End Function

End Class
```

Description: When the MainWindow.xaml is launched the main system parameters are initiated and the timer kicks in. Every 30 milliseconds (not 100) the main program loop runs. I copied most of the code from the example code here. Looks like a state machine set up, where they used Mode to switch between stages of calibration. A "GO" button is used right now to start the calibration by switch one flag, but the video feed runs continuously. The bottom function is to compensate for the fact that old picturebox.image liked .tobitmap(), but image.source does not which I am using.

So, hit GO button, wait for 100 images to be saved, calculate points and save all that data. Calculate extrinsics and intrinsics, find skewing maps, and apply maps to feed.

When CameraCalibration.CalibrateCamera is finished it spits out an error as double, and MsgBox shows what that is.
When MsgBox fires and tells me my error, I am seeing numbers as high as 85-105 where the guide is telling me it should be minimized as close to 0 as possible.

Then when the altered image appears it is heavily skewed.

[image: Video feed on the calibration]

Bottom left: Video Feed. Bottom Right: Grayed feed with corners found.
The Top Left image is supposed to be the corrected one. 
The last time I ran the program, it actually heavily distorted the image to look like a fishbowl.

Does anyone else have experience with this and can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Some additional info: 
All other code I have found online, when using .calibratecamera has not been in VB and in addition has taken one less argument. "termCriteria" is a variable that I had to figure out how to set, and I have never seen other code that had to use it.

For code conversion I used this site:
[Code converter.](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=c3d82aab-4c61-4b66-952f-840e51af3aa2#convert-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So for anyone who comes across this thread. I mixed up the Height and Width Variables. The Code started reading width then height, and after wards ran the calibration as height then width.

I made sure that it was formatted the same way as the example code all the way through, and now I have errors of ~ 1.